# Google Maps API v3.30: Using forEach on a declared data layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API v3.30 to display multiple GeoJSON map layers. I have declared each layer separately, and I am able to load the GeoJSON, set styles, and switch between each layer without any issue. However when I try to use the forEach method on the declared layer, any code within is not run.

```
var myLayer = new google.maps.Data();
myLayer.loadGeoJson('Content/Maps/myGeoJsonData.geojson');
myLayer.setStyle( function (feature) {return defaultStyle(feature); });
myLayer.setMap(map);
myLayer.forEach(function (feature) { console.log("Test"); }); // Doesn't work
```

Everything above works except for the forEach method. I've tried rearranging the order of each line but still the only line that doesn't run is the forEach

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. You say in a comment to my answer it depends on your data.  Please provide some sample data the exhibits the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the original GeoJSON data as it is sensitive. I simplified the map and I was then able to use the forEach. I'll have to answer this question myself once I can replicate the error. The only differences I can see between the Google sample and my own map is Google uses Polygons and I'm using Multipolygons, but I'll have to dig deeper

Comment: Don't post anything sensitive, create a [mcve] that exhibits the issue,  with random data (or start with google's example and add stuff like your data until it exhibits the problem).  Doing that might make this question irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

`loadGeoJson` is asynchronous.  You need to wait until it completes loading the data from the request before calling `.forEach`.  Use its optional callback function:

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data):

> loadGeoJson(url:string, options?:Data.GeoJsonOptions, callback?:function(Array))
>   Return Value:  None
>   Loads GeoJSON from a URL, and adds the features to the collection.

```
var myLayer = new google.maps.Data();
myLayer.loadGeoJson(
  'Content/Maps/myGeoJsonData.geojson', {},
  function(features) {
    console.log("loadGeoJson callback "+features.length);
    myLayer.forEach(function(feature) {
      console.log("Test");
    }); 
  });
myLayer.setStyle( function (feature) {return defaultStyle(feature); });
myLayer.setMap(map);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cjpycnsa/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {
        lat: -28,
        lng: 137
      },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


  var myLayer = new google.maps.Data();
  myLayer.loadGeoJson(
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json', {},
    function(features) {
      console.log("loadGeoJson callback " + features.length);
      myLayer.forEach(function(feature) {
        console.log("Test");
      });
    });
  myLayer.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I'm able to get the object before the forEach call, if I do a console.log(myLayer) inbetween the load and the forEach I return the loaded layer with all the data

Comment: +1 because you gave me the idea to debug the GeoJSON itself, when I swap my GeoJSON with the Google sample I'm able to use the forEach. So it has something to do with the file. Not sure where to go from there though as the map itself and all it's geometry are displaying correctly....